# background upload files to server in php

Tags: php, file-upload, drupal-7

I have to upload heavy file 100-1000MB from client to server. I want to upload background (means if user close browser then files also uploading)

Is this possible. If yes then give me some idea.

If no then open any minimized window that upload file in background not to related to parent window.

Comment: i don't think it is possible.

Comment: The clients connection to your server will be closed as soon as they close the browser - unless - you use another connection independent of the browser. This could be done by creating a PHP process to connect via FTP to the client.. but that makes a fairly big assumption that the client has FTP server capabilities, and is happy to give access to your script.. which is highly unlikely unless you know the client.

Comment: @Pudge601 In file upload $_FILES gives me php temp path so how can i do with ftp/ncftpput.

Comment: I'd rather combine this with some browser-independent environment, like Java perhaps.

Comment: @Voitcus can you some more idea or link how to do this using java?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but I imagine this by opening a Java applet in the browser. I **think** you can keep applet working (or rather a program run from Java) even if the browser is closed. But this is only an assumption; I don't know anything about privileges and security problems this might cause (I can imagine lots of them if this works). I suggest to ask StackOverflow's Java guys. By using PHP only it is not possible.

Comment: If you're going to be doing it via FTP, a new process can be created separately on the server to do the retrieving of the file. Give it the details for ftp login, and path to file, and run the process in the background.

Comment: @Pudge601  I am using "ncftpput -b -u username -p password ip /home /home/chetan/Large.flv &". My problem is that how to get actual file path.

Comment: You need what is essentially a custom FTP client - this is no small task. You'd need some way of allowing your client to connect through FTP in your browser to the client's FTP server, find the file, and then send the path back to the server to run a process to fetch it. All of this is, however, trivial, since as I said before, it's highly unlikely that your client using your site has an FTP server installed and is willing to send you the details for it.